# jquery change sometimes event prevents click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

In the following [example](http://jsbin.com/ARUhAVij/2/), there is a simple input field and a button.

```
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="in">
    <input type="button" value="click" id="button">
    </body>
```

There is a change-event-function on the input field and a click-event-function on the button.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#in').change(function() { 
        console.log('change event');
        //window.alert('change event');
      });
      $('#button').click(function() { 
        console.log('click event'); 
      });
    });
```

On changing the value of the input field and immediately clicking the button (without leaving the cursor), my expectation is, that both events are fired. Unfortunately this behavior depends on the code executed inside the change-function e.g. on uncommenting the window.alert line, the click event is NOT fired - or the click-event-function is not executed. Why? How can I avoid code, which prevents the click-event-function from executing?

**Update**:
instead of the window.alert, the jquery.hide has the [same effect](http://jsbin.com/ARUhAVij/4/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#in').change(function() { 
        console.log('change event');
        $('#hide').hide();
      });
      $('#button').click(function() { 
        console.log('click event'); 
      });
    });
```

Comment: alert() is modal, that's explain it

Comment: Because you didn't actually click the button. you instead left the input, then the browser immediately froze while waiting for you to click the ok button on the alert. While it is *froze*, or *blocked*, you can't interact with the page. To fix it, don't use alert.

Comment: still wandering ,what you are looking for?

Comment: look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G4QyT/2/ for [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click) to fire the mousedown and mouseup needs to happen in a single element... but as soon as the mousedown happens the change event is fired and the alert is displayed... which is a modal window... that prevent the mouseup thus the click operation is not completed

Comment: @A.Wolff I guess my example is not quite good. The real case does not use alert, but modifies the DOM a lot using jQuery. But there is no modal window. Are there any other restrictions? Maybe it depends on the execution time of the code inside the change-function?

Comment: @Meise2000 javascript is single thread language, so no! But could be due to some async method in some way. Cannot help you more without knowing what you are doing...

Comment: @A.Wolff the jQuery-hide-function has the same effect like alert as you can see in the [modified example](http://jsbin.com/ARUhAVij/4).

Comment: @Meise2000 because you don't have time to click on the button due to how the html is rendered (button element moved as soon as top element is hidden) see if you put hidden element below the button: http://jsbin.com/ARUhAVij/5/edit

Comment: @A.Wolff great! That's it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire both of two events, you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#in').change(function() { 
        console.log('change event');
        window.alert('change event');
        $('#button').click();
      });
      $('#button').click(function() { 
        console.log('click event'); 
      });
    });
```

Comment: That only will solve it, if i know which button is clicked or if - like in the stripped down example - there is just one button. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean "which button"?. This is an id #button, so it's unique and you must know it.

Comment: Yes, in the example above, I can solve it. But in my case there are many buttons and many input fields. I just wanted to spare you the details and I stripped down the example.

Comment: I see. If you have a lot of input field or a lot of button, just give them a class and you can do like example again. Something like $('.buttonClass').click();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    console.log('click event'); 
});
```

The mousedown event will occur before textbox change and click events so that you need to set time out and check the changed value of the text box if required.